# Retrofit Client w/ Optional Gson Converter

Tags: kotlin, retrofit

I have some API clients I would like to pass in an optional Json Decoder. For instance, some APIs return JSON in the following manner:

```
{
   "title": "Some Name",
   "more": "data"
}
```

and others return data in the following manner:

```
{
    "key": {
        "title": "Some Name",
        "more": "data"
    }
}
```

What I would like to do is pass in an optional gson converter.

```
fun createService(): ApiInterface {
    return buildService()
}


fun <T>createService(targetClass: Class<T>, key: String): ApiInterface {
    targetClass: Class<T>
    key: String
    var gson: Gson = GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapter(targetClass, RestDeserializer(targetClass, key))
        .create()

       return buildService(gson)
   } 

   fun buildService(gson: Gson?): ApiInterface {
       // build my builder
       val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
           .baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)

            /// I WANT TO PASS gson here IF it exists..
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson??))  <------- Pass in gson ONLY if it's not null??

            .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.createAsync())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(NetworkResponseAdapterFactory())
            .client(client.build())
            .build()

       return retrofit.create(ApiInterface::class.java)  
   }
```

If I pass in gson when it's null, I get an error

How can I pass in gson ONLY if it isn't null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand your question correctly. If I do, you just need a null check.

```kotlin
fun buildService(gson: Gson?): ApiInterface {
    val retrofitBuilder = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)

    if(gson != null) {
        retrofitBuilder.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
    }

    val retrofit = retrofitBuilder.
        .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
        .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.createAsync())
        .addCallAdapterFactory(NetworkResponseAdapterFactory())
        .client(client.build())
        .build()

    return retrofit.create(ApiInterface::class.java)  
}
```